# Safari 6, it does not resize properly (Scrollbar does not stay at the bottom)

Tags: jquery, html, css, safari, resize

If you tested the site on Chrome, FF or IE(8) and resize the windows (height) than can you see that scrollbar moves dynamically with the content inside middle yellow box.

**My problem is that in Safari, it does not resize properly. (Scrollbar does not stay at the bottom of the div)**

Here is  the **[JSBIN TEST FILE](http://jsbin.com/aPoMEzI/2/edit)**

**HTML:**

```
<body>
    <div id="message_box">

        <div id="header"> Header </div>

        <div id="content">

            <ul id="msg_list">

                <li>Test file</li>
                <li>Test file</li>
                <li>Test file</li>
                <li>Test file</li> <!-- ...and so on -->   

           </ul>

       </div>

       <div id="footer"> Footer </div>

    </div>
</body>
```

**CSS:**

```
html, body {
    height: 100%;
}

#message_box {
    width: 500px;
    float: left;
}

 #header {
    width: 500px;
    height: 50px;
    background-color: #aaa;
    text-align: center;
}

#content {
    min-height: 150px;
    width: 500px;
    position: relative;
    background-color: #ffa;
    border: solid #cdd1d8;
    border-width: 2px 0 2px 0;
    overflow-y: scroll !important;
    overflow-x: hidden;
}

#msg_list {
    width: 100%;
    position: absolute;
    bottom: 100px;
    margin-bottom: 50%;
    left: 0;
    display: block;
    height: 1px;
}

#footer {
    height: 300px;
    padding: 10px;
    background-color: #aaa;
    text-align: center;
}
```

jQuery (v1.10.1):

```
$(document).ready(auto_size);

$(window).on("resize", auto_size);

function auto_size() {

    var body_content_msg = $("body").height(),
        header_content_msg = $("#header").height(),
        footer_content_msg = $("#footer").height(),
        newHeight = body_content_msg - header_content_msg - footer_content_msg + "px";

    $("#content").css("height", newHeight);
}

$(document).ready(function(){

    $("#content").scrollTop($("#content")[0].scrollHeight);

});
```

Someone can me explain why this happens in **Safari** and how to handle this?

**UPDATE:**

You have to resize the window up/down to see that the **"Test file // FIRST MESSAGE //"** disappear in Safari.

Here is a [Safari 6 bug Test](http://www.cybmed.com/w/safari6bug/):

> ... *Safari 6 will perform the scroll, but will report an incorrect value after the scroll is performed unless you repeat the call to $scrollElement.scrollTop().* ...

Comment: It looks the same in Firefox (latest) and Safari (latest) on OS X. Does this happen in Safari 5 on a PC? Keep in mind that Safari for PC is discontinued and the latest version is over a year old.

Comment: @insertusernamehere I tested on OS X / Safari 6

Comment: Works fine for me in  OS X / Safari 6.0.2

Comment: To specify your problem: When you resize the browser window vertically the scrollbar for the yellow array in the left doesn't change it's size. Right?

Comment: Ah I see, Safari is automatically scrolling up a little bit.

Comment: I think you need to cache the new height inside a variable and force the scroll position to the bottom.

Comment: @Shivam - That is not what I want.. If you scroll a little bit and then you resize the windows then make no sense when you force the content to the bottom.

Comment: aldanux, you can keep bottom position in variable. and without margin-bottom: 50% works fine in safari

Comment: @ArtemGorlachev - I have answered my question self...but you have brought me to the idea to experiment with the `margin-bottom`!! Thanks a lot! :-)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

After (many) days to try out, I found finally the solution.

I change in CSS the `margin-bottom: 50%;` to `margin-bottom: 200px;`

```
#msg_list {
        width: 100%;
        position: absolute;
        bottom: 100px;
        margin-bottom: 200px;
        left: 0;
        display: block;
        height: 1px;
}
```

And that is all! :-)

Anyway thanks to all who have helped me!

Answer (score 0):

find below the answer that will solve your problem.

**HTML** + **CSS** remain the same.

**JS**

```
$(document).ready(auto_size);

$(window).resize(function () {
    auto_size();
    $("#content").scrollTop($("#content")[0].scrollHeight);
});



function auto_size() {

    var body_content_msg = $("body").height(),
        header_content_msg = $("#header").height(),
        footer_content_msg = $("#footer").height(),
        newHeight = body_content_msg - header_content_msg - footer_content_msg + "px";

    $("#content").css("height", newHeight);
}

$(document).ready(function () {

    $("#content").scrollTop($("#content")[0].scrollHeight);

});
```

Basically you need to call again the function that scrolls the scroll bar every time you resize your window.

Enjoy :)

Comment: Hey thanks.. but this is not what I want or solve my problem. The problem is when you scroll to up to read, for example the "// Last Message //", and then you resize the windows, that go to the first message again and you have to scroll up to read the last message.

Comment: @aldanux i know your issue, because i was able to replicate it. The code i provided you solves it. Regardless if you resize your browser the scroll bar will always stay at the end - you will be able to read the last message at all times.

Comment: @Thanos.. This issue is only in Safari 6.* (I've no problem with this tested Browser: Chrome, FF and IE 8 <- That surprise me :-)) so the question is "Why this bug in Safari and how can I resolve this?". Your solution is good but I need a better one (If exist!). My hope fades slowly (day by day) if there is a solution for this issue...

Comment: @aldanux I know your problem is with safari. With the provided code you can solve this issue in Safari and it will work on all other browsers. Safari handles the scrollbar differently than the other browsers, when you resize your browser, the scrollable container doesn't keep the scrollbar's previous location, so with my solution every time you resize your browser we re-position the scrollbar to the bottom.